# Removing element from XML in C# with an attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I m new into C#. I m trying to delete the element having attribute **name = "companyKey"**

I have tried to do so through the following code:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(results);
xml.Elements("NewDataSet")
   .Attributes("companyKey").Remove();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var reader = xml.CreateReader())
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

However, It is not excluding/deleting the element. Any help/clue would be appreciated.

The XML I m using to apply this code is:

```
<NewDataSet>
 <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:element name="Table1">
      <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="companyKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />      
            <xs:element name="phoneVisits" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
       </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not enough information for us to help you.  Please review [ask].

Comment: I'm confused. If you're trying to delete the `element` with `name="companyKey"`, then why does your code delete the `operatorImageUrl` attribute in any root `NewDataSet` element?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it. I want to delete the element with the name="companyKey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Elements` will only return the child elements from the current node, not the children's children (otherwise known as descendants).  You then select and remove the *attribute*, not the element.  As that child element and attribute don't exist, you have an empty sequence so nothing is removed.

What you want to do is find all descendant elements where the element contains your name attribute.  Try:

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xml.Descendants(xs + "element")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "companyKey")
    .Remove();
```